# Existence of Borel measure on the Real line.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

[image]

If I choose $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as such that $F(x)=\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor +1$. Clearly this function in increasing and right continuous.

I want to show there exist a Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $a<b$ we $F(b)-F(a)=\mu((a,b])$.

In the book, they suppose that $\mu$ is finite Borel measure, but how do I show the existence of Borel measure?

Comment: Do you know that it suffices show that  $\mu$ is a premeasure on the collection of finite disjoint unions of $h$-intervals?

Comment: Can you give some hint about your idea. 1.15 Proposition says If F is increasing and right continuous. If $(a_i,b_i]$ are disjoint h-intervals, and $\mu_0(\cup(a_i,b_i])=\sum[F(b_i)-F(a_i)$. Then $\mu_0$ is a premeasure on the Algebra.   Can you give me some hints?

Comment: If $(a_j, b_j]$ is a finite sequence of disjoint intervals show directly that defining $\mu_0(\bigcup_{n =1}^n (a_j, b_j]) = \sum_{j=0}^n [F(b_j)-F(a_j)], \\$ makes $\mu_0$ into a premeasure.